# BSOD ATTEMPTED_WRITE_TO_READONLY_MEMORY / KERNEL_SECURITY_CHECK_FAILURE Win10/11

Tags: bsod, crash

For a few days now, my gaming beast has been crashing when I play certain games. Before the release of the (latest) AMD drivers I never had a light crash (black screen, game to desktop) but since this release, which is designed to fix crashes on Baldur's Gate III, my PC doesn't work too well any more. (I have an i9 13900k and a Sapphire RX 7900XTX.) Here are the WhoCrashed reports:

*On Sun 10/09/2023 14:11:06 your computer crashed or a problem was reported*

**Crash dump file:  C:\Windows\Minidump\091023-7031-01.dmp (Minidump)

Bugcheck code:  0x139(0x2, 0xFFFF858C05E37740, 0xFFFF858C05E37698, 0x0)
Bugcheck name: KERNEL_SECURITY_CHECK_FAILURE
Bug check description: The kernel has detected the corruption of a critical data structure.
Analysis: This particular bugcheck may be caused by malware or a security product that does not follow programming guidelines. This can also be caused by memory corruption. This is possibly a software problem. There is a possibility that this is caused by memory corruption. Memory corruption can be caused by a faulty driver, faulty RAM, overheating and more. Read this article on memory corruption. Read this article on thermal issues**

*On Sun 10/09/2023 14:11:06 your computer crashed or a problem was reported*

**Crash dump file:  C:\Windows\MEMORY.DMP (Kernel memory dump)

Bugcheck code:  0x139(0x2, 0xFFFF858C05E37740, 0xFFFF858C05E37698, 0x0)
Bugcheck name: KERNEL_SECURITY_CHECK_FAILURE
Bug check description: The kernel has detected the corruption of a critical data structure.
Analysis: This particular bugcheck may be caused by malware or a security product that does not follow programming guidelines. This can also be caused by memory corruption. This is possibly a software problem. There is a possibility that this is caused by memory corruption. Memory corruption can be caused by a faulty driver, faulty RAM, overheating and more. Read this article on memory corruption. Read this article on thermal issues**

*On Sat 09/09/2023 15:29:17 your computer crashed or a problem was reported*

**Crash dump file:  C:\Windows\Minidump\090923-8265-01.dmp (Minidump)

Bugcheck code:  0xEF(0xFFFF80050D75F0C0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
Bugcheck name: CRITICAL_PROCESS_DIED
Bug check description: This indicates that a critical system process died.
Analysis: This particular bugcheck may be caused by malware or a security product that does not follow programming guidelines. This can also be caused by memory corruption. This is possibly a software problem. There is a possibility that this is caused by memory corruption. Memory corruption can be caused by a faulty driver, faulty RAM, overheating and more. Read this article on memory corruption. Read this article on thermal issues**

*On Sat 09/09/2023 15:27:55 your computer crashed or a problem was reported*

**Crash dump file:  C:\Windows\Minidump\090923-8046-01.dmp (Minidump)

Bugcheck code:  0xA(0x8, 0x2, 0x0, 0xFFFFF8044A64D721)
Bugcheck name: IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL
Bug check description: This indicates that Microsoft Windows or a kernel-mode driver accessed paged memory at DISPATCH_LEVEL or above. This is a software bug.
Analysis: This is a typical software problem. Most likely this is caused by a bug in a driver.**

(Not undervolting or overclocking my specs)(I tried a lot of things)
Minidumps : https://1drv.ms/f/s!AqE6jCe98gQkhPlyA2uMm-SVQ33HoA?e=EWfVSe

Comment: Lots for you to check:    https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/bug-check-0x139--kernel-security-check-failure.    Get the Update APP and Diagnostics APP for your computer.  Update ALL driver and then test ALL hardware.

Comment: I downloaded the `.dmp` files and I see that all the crashes are inside the kernel, with no drivers on the stack. I suggest running [MemTest86](https://www.memtest86.com/) overnight as a test of your hardware.

Comment: Hoi, I retryed again and again... didn't work, i changed CM/RAM, ssd's i reinstalled windows, but he keeps crashing...

Comment: Probably a CPU issue ?